# Metrics on most accessed standard tabs

Tags: user-management, eventlogfile

Is there anyway to gather metrics on most accessed tabs..Just wanted to know what tabs are accessed most by the users. I see salesforce has event monitoring and not sure that would help..I wanted to track with in Salesforce itself.

Would appreciate any input.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to get that level of granularity in tracking user telemetry. Currently event monitoring is limited to login forensics.

This will likely expand in the future, so you might want to keep tabs on that, or have your sales or customer success contact person at Salesforce ask if there are any pilot programs related to this that meet your criteria.